# Cannot save key URL of cms page is "/cookie" despite of that don't have any url in URL Rewrites of Module SEO in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, magento24

I created a CMS page named Cookie but when I save it with the key URL "cookie" it cannot save and shows an error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is showing due to URL key(`cookie`) already exist, Please change URL key for the new cookie page.

Comment: I used the SEO module and when I went to the URL Rewrite section, I didn't see any /cookie used.

Comment: check url from here, Admion ->   Marketing -> SEO&Search -> URL Rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for that is that the URL key already in use somewhere else in Magento. To solve this, you should navigate to your admin CMS  page, click on on the **Search Engine Optimization tab**, and update the **URL key**. Choose a new unique URL key instead of **Cookie**, and then page will be created.

Comment: I used the SEO module and when I went to the URL Rewrite section, I didn't see any /cookie used.

Comment: Actually Magento use the "cookie" as a path by default in core files. So you are not allowed to use it again.

File Path in which it was used : vendor\magento\module-cms\Observer\NoCookiesObserver.php

Comment: But i really want to create cms page with key url is "/cookie", you know how to do it ?

Comment: To achieve this, you have to disable the Magento_Cookie module which is not advisable, as doing so may create additional issues, especially since there are dependent modules such as Magento_GoogleAnalytics, Magento_GoogleGtag, and Magento_GoogleOptimizer. Disabling the cookie module could also disrupt user logins. Instead, a recommended approach is to add a specific value before the slash, like "/xxx/cookie."

Comment: i saw in module-cookie have file routes.xml in folder etc/frontend, inside routes file have frontName is "cookie". I change that frontName to another name and then i can save cms page with url is "cookie". Should i do that?

Comment: @PhanHuy I recommend against altering the default route since other dependent modules may be utilizing it, and any changes could potentially lead to issues.